# Testing a Date from a database that uses to_date and testing against LocalTimeDate

Tags: java, unit-testing, java-8, localdate

I have a old program and I upgraded it to Java 8. Now I would like to take advantage of LocalDateTime. I have already updated the entity and in the Database the value reads `10-APR-1990`.

However I am getting the following error:

`java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '10-APR-90' could not be parsed at index 3`

In my test I attempt to parse it using `DateTimeFormatter`.

Test:

```
@Test
    public void testLocalDateTime() throws Exception {

        DateTimeFormatter formatter =
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.US);

        Tcan1990 applicant = tcan1990Repository.findOne(new Tcan1990PK("000000009", 888067));

        assertEquals(LocalDateTime.parse("10-APR-90",formatter),applicant.getPymtDt());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your test case to use case insensitive formatter and parse the date string to LocalDate with time set to start of the day to get the LocalDateTime.

```
@Test
public void testLocalDateTime() throws Exception {

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseCaseInsensitive().appendPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy").toFormatter(Locale.US);

    Tcan1990 applicant = tcan1990Repository.findOne(new Tcan1990PK("000000009", 888067));

    assertEquals(LocalDate.parse("10-APR-1990", formatter).atStartOfDay(), applicant.getPymtDt());

}
```

Comment: I cannot add `applicant.getPymtDt().atStartOfDay()` and I am still getting the same error. The field is LocalDateTIme

Comment: Updated code to remove the atStartOfDay(). is there a time in the string that you are passing ? The assertion is going to fail. are you okay with asserting just the local date part ?     assertEquals(LocalDate.parse("10-APR-1990", formatter), applicant.getPymtDt().toLocalDate());

Comment: My IDE is warning of `inconvertible types LocalDate and LocalDateTime` and I got and error saying `java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :2008-02-08
Actual   :2008-02-08T00:00` so it appears to be working but I need to fix the parse

Comment: did you add  applicant.getPymtDt().toLocalDate() to the actual ? seems like it is still local date time. toLocalDate() will extract the local date from pymtDt.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- The month needs to be in camel case: `"10-Apr-90"`.
- Because there's no time aspect to what you're parsing, you should be using `LocalDate` and not `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: In most cases, users cannot control the exact form of input but has to adjust the formatter to match the input. Therefore your first advise is more or less pointless unless you also recommend any kind of string preprocessing.

Comment: Very true.  However, this was a hard-coded string, so I believe the answer remains relevant to _this specific problem_.